Stored Cross-Site Scripting through cookies
Recently we have scanned our project using checkmarx and which reported some Vulnerabilities.
I am looking for some advice on how this vulnerability can be better handled.
Stored Cross-Site Scripting: In a scenario, an object is received from the database, and a value of the same is used to construct a string, which is set as the value of the cookie
Customer customer = new Customer().GetCustomerByCustomerID(customerID);
HttpCookie sessionCookie = new HttpCookie(SessionCookieName + t, string.IsNullOrEmpty(renewedToken) ? Token.EncryptToken(customer.customerName) : renewedToken);
sessionCookie.Path = applicationPath + "; SameSite=None; Secure";
sessionCookie.HttpOnly = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(sessionCookie);

Here vulnerability is reported to say that an attacker can store data ahead of time and then read it from a database. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.
I already spent time reading different blogs and set HttpOnly to true, but that's not solving the problem. Here customer.CustomerName can accept some special characters, so I cannot encode it directly. Any help on how this can be better handled would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.
